# AWS S3 lifecycle rule on multiple folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket that contains many folders and I would like to apply a lifecycle rule only fore some folders within the bucket.
It's possible to apply an AWS S3 lifecycle rule on multiple folders(PREfixes) within a bucket?

For example I have a bucket s3://mybucket that contains folder1, folder2 folder3, folder4. I would like to send to Glacier only folder1 and folder 4.

My question is: I need to create new rule for every folder(prefix) or it is a possibility to insert all of them in a single rule?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copied from the [S3 Managing Lifecycle Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/LifecycleConfiguration.html):

> You can define a rule for all objects or a subset of objects in the bucket (by specifying the key name prefix).

In other words, a rule applies to all objects that share the same prefix. If you have many different prefixes (such as `folder1`, `folder2`, etc) you must copy the rule and change the prefix accordingly. Alternatively, you can add a new common prefix (e.g. `send-to-glacier/folder1`, `send-to-glacier/folder2` and then create a new rule for the `send-to-glacier` prefix).

Comment: Good hint to create a new common prefix!