# How can I delete old files by name in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Much like in [S3-Bucket/Management/Lifecycles using prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969953/aws-s3-lifecycle-rule-on-multiple-folders/38970507#38970507), I'd like to prune old files that have certain words.

I'm looking to remove files that start with `Screenshot` or has `screencast` in the filename older than 365 days.

## Examples

- `/Screenshot 2017-03-19 10.11.12.png`
- `folder1/Screenshot 2019-03-01 14.31.55.png`
- `folder2/sub_folder/project-screencast.mp4`

I'm currently testing if lifecycle prefixes work on files too.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a program to do it, such as this Python script:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

keys_to_delete = [{'Key': object['Key']} 
                  for object in response['Contents'] 
                  if object['LastModified'] < datetime(2018, 3, 20)
                     and ('Screenshot' in object['Key'] or 'screencast' in object['Key'])
                 ]

s3.delete_objects(Bucket='my-bucket', Delete={'Objects': keys_to_delete})
```

You could modify it to be "1 year ago" rather than a specific date.

Comment: Great, that helped a lot...
a prefix in the list_objects call could be added which will be helpful if you want to delete from a specific sub-folder
response = s3.list_objects_v2({"Bucket": 'my-bucket', "Prefix": "path/to/subfolder/"})

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can apply lifecycle rules with wildcards such as `*screencast*`, only with prefixes such as "taxes/" or "taxes/2010".

For your case, I would probably write a script (or perhaps an Athena query) to filter an [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) report for those files that match your name/age conditions, and then prune them.

Of course, you could write a program to do this as @John Rotenstein suggests. The one time that might not be ideal is if you have millions or billions of objects because the time to enumerate the list of objects would be significant. But it would be fine for a reasonable number of objects.

Comment: So, the prefix `taxes/2010` would delete/expire a file named `taxes/2010-10-02.txt` because the file starts with `2010`?

Comment: Yes, but because the full key starts with taxes/2010, not specifically because the filename starts with 2010. I haven't tested this but that's how it should work: anything beginning with the stated prefix.